# how to change value change text in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I want to when change TVA value change text But in the end, the same result
They appear "NET TTC" in both cases

Function :

```
    public function invoice()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Invoice::class, 'invoice_id', 'id');
    }
    public function tvaText(){ 
        if( $this->TVA_value == 0 ){
            $this->tva_text='NET TTC';
        }elseif($this->TVA_value != 0){
            $this->tva_text='Total TTC';
        }
        return $this->tva_text;
    }
```

Show :

```
            @foreach($invoice->details as $item)
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{ $loop->iteration }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $item->product_name }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $item->quantity }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $item->unit_price }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $item->row_sub_total }}</td>
                            </tr>
                           

                            </tbody>
                            <tfoot>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="3"></td>
                                <th colspan="2">TVA value </th>
                                <td>{{ $invoice->TVA_value }}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="3"></td>
                                <th colspan="2">sub total</th>
                                <td>{{ $invoice->sub_total }}</td>
                            </tr>
                            
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="3"></td>
                                <th colspan="2">TVA total</th>
                                <td>{{ $invoice->TVA_total }}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="3"></td>
                                <th colspan="2">{{ $item->**tvaText()** }}</th>
                                <td>{{ $invoice->TTC_total }}</td>
                            </tr>
            @endforeach
```

[image]

[image]

Please see pictures so that it becomes clear to you what I mean
does anyone know how to change text or any other method to achieve?

Comment: can you add code which alter the value of  $this->tva_text? your logic to display tvaText is correct but it seems value is not updating,you should check for the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it easily on blade.

```
 @if($invoice->TVA_value == 0 )         
      <td>NET TTC</td>         
@else
      <td> Total TTC </td>        
@endif
```